# Javascript, pause/resume window.load event

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, onload

I have an unusual problem that is beyond my client side skill set.  I have an html page with two consecutive `script` tags in the body.  Both `script` tags fire an ajax request to retrieve content and then put it in the DOM.  I control the first `script` tag, and I don't have any control or knowledge about the second `script` tag.  I just know it makes an ajax call and put stuff in the DOM.  I also know that my tag is first.

I want my script tag to fire immediately and pause/stop the second tag.  Then, contingent on what my ajax returns, I may choose to execute the second script tag.  How do I do this?

I wrote a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SWkLX/1/) demonstrating my problem.  I substituted `settimeout`'s for ajax calls and `Math.random` for my decision.  Note that the `settimeout` duration for the first one (my one) is very long, 3 seconds, and the duration for the second one (the one I don't control is very short, .5 seconds.  What's happening now is that they are both running immediately.  The second message  comes in at .5 seconds, and the message from the first comes in at 3 seconds 50% of the time.

I want the first script to run, wait 3 seconds, make a decision and either print the first message immediately, or call the second script which would wait an additional .5 seconds to print the second message.  I should never see both messages at the same time, and I should never see the second message before 3.5 seconds.

Again, I don't know any knowledge over the contents of script two.  You could easily hide id=`ext_div` in this case, but I don't know what that id is.  That is not the answer I want.  I was thinking about grabbing the event on the first script and doing something to that, `stopPropagation` or something like that at the `TODO1` comment.  But that doesn't work.  Event if it did, I would need a `resumePropgation` function which I don't event think exists.

Comment: It's impossible to conditionally execute the content of a following script element, since by the time a previous script knows it exists, it will almost certainly have already been executed. Such scripts can only be controlled by controlling how and when they are added to the document.

Answer (score 0):

> I want my script tag to fire immediately and pause/stop the second tag. Then, contingent on what my ajax returns, I may choose to execute the second script tag. How do I do this?

The only way to make that happen is to make your ajax call synchronous, e.g., pass `false` as the third argument to [`XMLHttpRequest#open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or whatever the equivalent is in the library you're using, if you're using one). There are **several reasons** why this is a **bad idea**, but if you absolutely, positively need your ajax call to complete before the next `script` tag is executed, that's the only way to do it. Of course, it means that any DOM elements defined below your `script` tag in the HTML document won't exist yet.

Comment: very interesting ....  To be honest, it isn't an ajax call, it's off domain, so I'm forced to use jsonp call which just appends a script tag to the head.  So I'm actually not doing an XMLHttpRequest (i think). The other script is most likely doing the same thing.  Sorry for not being clearer above.  Would your suggestion still work?

Comment: @Landon: No, if it's JSONP it wouldn't work -- and in fact, if it's JSONP, you can't do what you want to do. Time to start thinking about other approaches to solving the underlying requirement, I'm afraid. If you can control outputting the other script tag, for instance not including it in the HTML at all, but instead adding it when your code is done, then you can do something. But if you have no control over when the other script tag is added, it's impossible for you to hold up execution of it.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you want some sort of dependency management system for your front-end scripts.

Try out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). You could load in your script, run your ajax request, and depending on your logic, decide whether or not to load the second external script.

This is assuming you can control the markup on the page of course.